# Simple Matrix Multiplication with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to multiply a column vector into a row vector and then vectorize the above 2 dimensional matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\A{
    \begin{bmatrix}
        p_1 & p_2 & \cdots & p_N
\end{bmatrix}}


\def\B{
\begin{bmatrix}
    p_1q_1 & p_1q_2  &\cdots &p_1q_N\\
    p_2q_1 & p_2q_2  &\cdots &p_2q_N\\
    \vdots & & &  \vdots\\
    p_Nq_1 & p_Nq_2 &\cdots &p_Nq_N\\
\end{bmatrix}}

\def\C{
    \begin{bmatrix}
        q_1 \\
        q_2 \\
        \vdots \\
        q_N
\end{bmatrix}}

\def\D{
    \begin{bmatrix}
        p_1q_1 & p_1q_2 &\cdots &p_1q_N &p_2q_1 &\cdots &p_Nq_N
\end{bmatrix}}


\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{figure}
    \begin{equation}
    \C \A = \B   \Rightarrow  \D
    \end{equation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the above code produces what I actually  mean, but I want to draw it using Tikz with array shape for vectors.

[image: array shape]

can anybody help me on that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: (i) array shape doesn't exist, (ii) for matrices exist `matrix` library (iii) do you expect for each matrix separate image? (iv) what benefits you expect writing matrices by `tikz` (v) your equation is very wide ... please clarify your question.

Comment: @Zarko there is `left/right delimiter` option for `\matrix`

Comment: @percusse, i know. to me is not clear if op like to have image with of matrix equation or only `tikz` replacement for each matrix in equation :-(.

Comment: @Zarko I just want to change its appearance, I draw what I expected.

Comment: sorry, but i don't see any picture. is @Ignasi answer what you looking for? i must confess that i don't understand your question. to write equation on more complicated way?

Comment: this is the link of hand drawn picture :https://ibb.co/mPhsTw

Answer (score 3):

While OP answers Zarko's question, here it's a version with all matrices inside one `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\tikzset{
    every left delimiter/.style={xshift=1ex},
    every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-1ex},
    bmatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes,
        inner sep=0pt,
        left delimiter={[},
        right delimiter={]},
        nodes={anchor=center, inner sep=.3333em},
        }
}


\def\A{
    \begin{bmatrix}
        p_1 & p_2 & \cdots & p_N
\end{bmatrix}}


\def\B{
\begin{bmatrix}
    p_1q_1 & p_1q_2  &\cdots &p_1q_N\\
    p_2q_1 & p_2q_2  &\cdots &p_2q_N\\
    \vdots & & &  \vdots\\
    p_Nq_1 & p_Nq_2 &\cdots &p_Nq_N\\
\end{bmatrix}}

\def\C{
    \begin{bmatrix}
        q_1 \\
        q_2 \\
        \vdots \\
        q_N
\end{bmatrix}}

\def\D{
    \begin{bmatrix}
        p_1q_1 & p_1q_2 &\cdots &p_1q_N &p_2q_1 &\cdots &p_Nq_N
\end{bmatrix}}


\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{figure}
    \begin{equation}
    \C \A = \B   \Rightarrow  \D
    \end{equation}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (C) [bmatrix] {q_1 \\
        q_2 \\[-1ex]
        \vdots \\
        q_N\\};
\matrix (A) [bmatrix, right=3mm of C] {p_1 & p_2 & \cdots & p_N\\};
\node (eq) [right=1mm of A] {$=$};
\matrix (B) [bmatrix, right=1mm of eq] {
    p_1q_1 & p_1q_2  &\cdots &p_1q_N\\
   p_2q_1 & p_2q_2  &\cdots &p_2q_N\\[-1ex]
   \vdots & & &  \vdots\\
   p_Nq_1 & p_Nq_2 &\cdots &p_Nq_N\\};
\node (imp) [right=1mm of B] {$\Rightarrow$};
\matrix (D) [bmatrix, right=1mm of imp] {
    p_1q_1 & p_1q_2 &\cdots &p_1q_N &p_2q_1 &\cdots &p_Nq_N\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]